# Using Matlabs fprintf command

Tags: matlab, printf

I am compiling a function within matlab that will tell me

1. The third side of the triangle
2. The perimeter length of the triangle
3. The area of the triangle

I have come up with this so far

```
function findHypotenuse(a, b)
    c=sqrt(a^2+b^2);
    circumference = (a+b+c);
    area = (.5*(a*b));
    fprintf('Triangle has side c which is %g.\n',c)
    fprintf('Triangle has a circumference of %g.\n',circumference)
    fprintf('Triangle has area of %g.\n',area)
    fprintf('Triangle has area of %g.\n',area)
```

which in result give me something like this when put into the command window

```
   >> findHypotenuse(6,8)
      Triangle has side c which is 10.
      Triangle has a circumference of 24.
      Triangle has area of 24.
      Triangle has area of 24.
```

I need help in figuring out how to make it say something along the lines of 'A Triangle with side _ and side _ has side c which c' and same format for the other two things found.

Also* I want to compile a function which will tell me yes or no if the triangle is a isosceles triangle

Comment: fprintf('Triangle is isosceles ? Answer: %g.\n',(a==b));

Answer (score 1):

`fprintf('A triangle with sides %.1f and %.1f has a hypotenuse of %.1f and a circumference of %.1f\n', a, b, c, a+b+c);`

would seem to be what you need. If you want to be able to format your numbers differently, you could get really clever and add

```
fs = '%.3f';
fprintf(['A triangle with sides ' fs ' and ' fs ' has a hypotenuse of %.1f and a circumference of %.1f\n], a, b, c, a+b+c);
```

This would allow you to change the precision of your answer, and the formatting of all the numbers would be changed in the same way.